# Separate string to columns by each character

Tags: r, string

in my dataframe I have a column with long string like this

```
df$string 
AVDSFBKLDF
```

What I need is to separate each character and create new column for it. Name of the columns is q1, q2 and so on. For similar cases like spliting string by symbol and put it into the new columns I used this code

```
df %>% separate(string, into = paste0('q', 1:10), sep = "")
```

It worked fine but now when I want to split string by each characters I'm getting some blank warning my console and my code do not works.

Comment: Hiho @Sklenicka. I think it would help to get a bit more information. What does the warning say. What happens if you run the code. Are all entries in $string 10 characters long? Do you have some example data to share etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code. i have used stringr package str_split_fixed function to create new columns.

```
a<- c("AVDSFBKLDF")

library(stringr)
d<- data.frame(str_split_fixed(a, "", max(nchar(a))))
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Looks good, but I't not sure how to mutate my already created dataframe. I have x <- df %>% mutate(xy = str_split_fixed(string , "", max(nchar(a)))) And it do not works

Comment: rather that using mutate save the result in a new data frame i suggest

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` package provides the function `tstrsplit` that you might consider.

```
a<- c("AVDSFBKLDF", "GH", "ABCD")

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a)
DT_wide <- DT[, tstrsplit(a, "")]

# change column names
setnames(DT_wide, paste0("q", seq_len(ncol(DT_wide))))
DT_wide
#   q1 q2   q3   q4   q5   q6   q7   q8   q9  q10
#1:  A  V    D    S    F    B    K    L    D    F
#2:  G  H <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3:  A  B    C    D <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

If you want to continue to work with a dataframe, type `setDF(DT_wide)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
df<- data.frame(string=c("ABCDEF","GH"))
df %>% mutate(v=str_split(string,"(?=.)")) %>% unnest %>%
  filter(v!="") %>% 
  group_by(string) %>% mutate(k=paste0("q",row_number())) %>% ungroup %>%
  spread(k,v) 
## A tibble: 2 x 7
#  string q1    q2    q3    q4    q5    q6   
#  <fct>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 ABCDEF A     B     C     D     E     F    
#2 GH     G     H     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```